# How to run a JavaScript function with 1 - 1000000 as arguments

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find what number between 1-1000000 will return the largest return with a function. I have an idea of how to test each return against eachother, but I'm not sure how to optimally run my function one million times without my computer exploding. Is there a basic way to run a function with the arguments 1-1000000?

Comment: The call frames should get destroyed once the function returns, so unless for some reason you are executing each function at the same time in the same memory, your computer will not explode, it will just take a long time. Instead of keeping track of each result, you can track the max

Comment: I supposed I should be more straightforward, I'm wanting to test a collatz sequence generator to see what number between 1 and 1,000,000 will return the largest collatz sequence. I'm not sure how to test the function 1,000,000 times however.

Comment: If your function behaves nicely (like if it's convex, and at least continuous), you likely can "sample" the input space, eg jumping every 1000, and then refine the "area" where the maximum is most likely to be. And then find it 1000 times faster. But it's not doable if the results jump "randomly"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can call your function with numbers starting from 1 to a million.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
   yourFunction(i);
}
```

This might take a long time but your computer won't explode.

Comment: Its always so simple and my brain just refuses to realize it. Thank you!!

Comment: @JoshBangle that's part of programming! Glad I could help

Comment: You'll also need to remember the max value seen in another variable...

Comment: Yea I've got that part of the code figured out, I have a resetting array the values are being stored in that is being tested against the length of a storage array, the largest value will be the final stored, and printed.